# CSS padding bottom not working when adding dashed border

Tags: css

I've researched this and am unable to understand why my padding won't work for this div. I won't the dashed border to be evenly distributed around the image. (see below). Here is my CSS:

```
#jspsych-tree-stim-bottom-left, #jspsych-tree-stim-bottom-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Example of border problem:

[image: Example of border problem]

Comment: gimme some code! html, more css perhaps?

Comment: What happens if you change `center bottom` to just `center`?

Comment: Out of curiosity: How does your border show if its color is `rgba(0,0,0,0)`?

Comment: The code you posted produces this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2xogk42h/

Comment: @j08691 I think OP's using a background image: https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/2xogk42h/1/

Comment: @Siguza Entirely possible, which is why I said "code you posted" and voted to close it for not providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it further myself, I've convinced myself that the `bottom` in

```
background-position: center bottom;
```

is pulling the image to the bottom of its container. Take out the `bottom` if you want the margin and padding to work there

```
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it.